# Do I have to duplicate the navbar code on every page with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm currently making a site with bootstrap that has multiple pages. My approach was to create multiple html files, e.g. Index.html, Products.html, Contact.html.

Now, do I have to duplicate the code for my navbar in every of those files? This seems rather cumbersome, as when I want to change something in the navbar, I have to go change it in every single file.

(Of course the code won't be an exact duplicate, as e.g. the active class is different on each html page, but like 99% is common code)

I of course know that I could use a CMS like Joomla that would handle this for me. But if I don't want to take that step, is it possible with Bootstrap? Or is that not what Bootstrap is for?
Curiously, I couldn't get any google hit on that topic with my queries. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: You should look into the MVC architecture.

Comment: After gaining more experience in this area, I feel like I know the answer to my question, and it's slightly different / more general to the answers already posted, so I've put my own answer below and accepted that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like the best answer to this question is "No, it's not really possible with only Bootstrap", and even more important, "No, it's not what Bootstrap is for".

Bootstrap is a framework for developing the graphics and layout of websites, and it doesn't contain any "logic" for multi-page sites with menus and switching between them and stuff like that. (It does contain some logic, but it's for responsiveness w.r.t. different device sizes, and that's done in CSS).

What you really want is a web framework like Rails or Django, or a CMS, and then use Bootstrap on top of that for the design and layout. Or, any of the other suggested answers in PHP or Javascript for a more "home-built" solution.

Answer (score 7):

Even if you aren't going to use the backend aspect of it, I recommend switching the files to .php and using includes.

**EXAMPLE**

**PHP (page)**

```
<?php
    $active = "ID-THAT-CORRESPONDS-WITH-ID-IN-NAV-ANCHOR"; 
    include '_includes/header.php';
?>

    page body here

<?php
    include '_includes/footer.php';
?>
```

**PHP (header)**

```
<nav class="<?php echo $active; ?>">
    <a href="#" id="home">Home</a>
    <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
    <a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

**CSS/LESS**

```
nav {
    /* if nav has class of home, style id of home to active state */
    &.home #home {
        ...
    }

    /* if nav has class of about, style id of about to active state */
    &.about #about {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your header.php file is where you would have your nav/header/etc. Lets you update one file and have it update cross-site.

Comment: This doesn't seem to allow setting different navbar elements to active depending on which site you are on?

Comment: Shoot. Missed that part. Edited the answer to allow for it using that example.

Comment: Hm, I like the approach, however, one drawback is that it's probably not going to work with Brackets (the editor) as a PHP server is required.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution consist to create your website body (navbar + background) and then use javascript to load different html into the body. So navbar will not being duplicate.

Imagine two boxes, the first one contain all of your bloc that doesn't change (navbar). And the second who is containing all content. With second box inside the first box.