# Displaying navbar on multiple html pages using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been searching for the answer to this for a little while now. I am using the Bootstrap framework to create a portfolio website. I have completed my index.html with a fixed-top navbar:

[This is the home page. The top shows the navbar.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZgWA.jpg)

This navbar has links to a "bio" page, a "projects" dropdown menu, and a "contact" page. I have created separate html pages for each of these (ex: I have index.html, bio.html, contact.html, video.html, design.html, etc.). However, when I press the links, they do not show the navbar, nor any other formatting.

I have this code for the graphic design html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Graphic Design</title>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>Graphic Design</h1>
    <p>Creating</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what shows up:
[graphicdesign.html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmkc8.jpg)

I wanted to know if there is a way to have the navbar consistent on every HTML page in a project.

I have seen this: [Bootstrap Navbar in multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36130712/bootstrap-navbar-in-multiple-pages) but I am having a hard time loading it using jQuery.

I have also seen this: [Do I have to duplicate the navbar code on every page with Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675539/do-i-have-to-duplicate-the-navbar-code-on-every-page-with-bootstrap) but I don't want to use PHP.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 9):

First off, I congratulate you on your question.
It addresses one of the fundamental needs and most important principles in programming: [`DRY`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself), which is the  main reason behind the development and implementation of most common web technologies, such as `php` or `CSS` (which can be further DRY-ed by `LESS` or `SASS`).

***`php`***, for example, was invented and instantly widely adopted mostly because of this "very cool new (at the time) feature": All you had to do was change the extension from `.html` to `.php` and you were able to include other parts using:

```
<?php include "part.html"; ?>
```

Usually referenced as ***template/component loading***, this is also a common task using `JavaScript`. Quite a few libraries provide it. For example `jQuery` provides [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) while `AngularJS` enables you to use [`directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)s to include [template](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/templates)s, which could either be defined as inline or external `HTML`. In fact, all package dependency managers and all frameworks provide it in a form or another, because today's web is unthinkable without reusable components.

If you want to find more options, I suggest you start searching for combinations of `html`, `include`, `templates`, `loading` and `components`.

Be warned, most `JavaScript` libraries come with overhead. The most popular, however, usually provide some flexibility, allowing  you to selectively build only the functionality you want.

Including templates will, most probably, become part of core `HTML` if (and when) Microsoft's [HTML Components](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-HTMLComponents) submission to the World Wide Web Consortium will be adopted, using the `<component>` tag.
Currently, this is possible using `AngularJS`s `type:"E"` directives.

Comment: I'd love to know the reason for the down-vote and what exactly the down-voter thinks is either wrong or incomplete about my answer. I'd be happy to improve it.

Comment: I like how this answer addresses the problem at its core. I would also list some static site generators here. However I think it's worth noting that all of the javascript solutions currently come with an overhead by requiring extra libraries and HTTP requests compared to PHP and SSGs. *-(not the downvote)*

Comment: It may seem obvious but PHP is a server-side feature that you have to enable in order for this technique to work.  Installing and configuring PHP is easy and instructions may be found elsewhere.  
Javascript runs on the client (browser), it should be enabled by default and doesn't require server configuration.
For PHP production pages make sure that your hosting service supports PHP (many of them do).

Answer (score 6):

In order to include your `navbar` in every page you have to use either `php` or `javascript`. Otherwise you will simply have to copy paste the html mark-up in every page. just try this two steps--

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="footer">

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 $("#footer").load("footer.html"); 
 });
   </script>
```

NOTE:
Make sure you are not adding bootstrap `CDN s` in the footer.html file.

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comment by andrei, yes it is very important to know that my answer requires `jquery`.

In order to use jquery you need to use the following cdn in your `head` tag or you can download jquery and serve it from your own file system.

```
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying this out now.

To address your second point about copying and pasting the html markup, I did copy and past the entire index.html code into the other pages, but they were not showing up correctly/the same as the index.

Comment: Greate hope it helps!

Comment: @Abby: when you are copying the mark-up don't copy the entire mark-up. Just copy the header portion. also don't forget to include the necessary styling css sheets. but jquery is thebetter way to do it.

Comment: @neophyte: there's nothing wrong with your answer. I believe we have a troll lurking around, as I've been downvoted too. What stops me from upvoting your answer is that you don't specify it uses jQuery. It's quite important, it will not work without jQuery.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: Thanks for pointing it out I am editing my answer.

Comment: You are welcome. One might argue that Twitter Bootstrap needs jQuery for it to work, but that's not true. The `JavaScript` part of it is totally optional.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu: I completely agree with you.

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing - and trying your suggestion above isn't working.  I have the javascript in the main HTML file, above the footer.  Is it supposed to go somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Since the title of the question is attracting people interested in Bootstrap nav-bar, here is a demonstration for a nav-bar. Both Bootstrap and jQuery are assumed.

My main point is to show how to correctly activate the nav-bar link which must be different in each page.

**nav-bar.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img alt="Brand" src="icon.png">
     <span class=px-2>My Site</span>
   </a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item ">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home Page </a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page2</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Now put the following code into the `<head>` section of each page that should show the nav-bar.

**Pay attention** to the `li:nth-child(2)` part. The number should be adapted in each html source according to its position in the nav-bar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function(){
      $.get("navbar.html", function(data){
          $("#common-navbar").html(data);
          $('.navbar-nav').find('li:nth-child(2)')
            .addClass('active')
            .find('a').append('<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>');
      });
  }
</script>
```

What is left now is to start each page with a `div` into which the nav-bar will be loaded:

```
<body>
  <div id="common-navbar"></div>
```